# sed, awk to replace xml elements

Tags: python, xml, awk, sed

i have an xml file, file.xml

like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<bookstore>

<book category="cooking">
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
  <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>30.00</price>
</book>

<book category="children">
  <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
  <author>J K. Rowling</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>

<book category="web">
  <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
  <author>James McGovern</author>
  <author>Per Bothner</author>
  <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
  <author>James Linn</author>
  <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>49.99</price>
</book>

<book category="web">
  <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
  <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>39.95</price>
</book>

</bookstore>
```

from which, i need to replace all values found in fileA.txt, with the ones found in fileB.txt

example of fileA.txt:

```
500
345
623
etc
```

values to be searched for

example of fileB.txt:

```
550
350
700
etc
```

so `<price>500</price>` should become `<price>550</price>`

I can run multiple times the below command,

```
sed -i 's/old/new/g' file.xml,
```

could you please show me a more clever way, in order to specify for example that the replacement must take only place in the  tag, and that if i need to replace 500 with 600, then 5000 will not become 6000?

Perhaps a python script would be preferred?

As in the comments, could you show me a python way, since i may be using the wrong tools, for the task?

Comment: Use an XML-aware tool. `Sed` or `awk` aren't the right tools for the job.

Comment: You can use `sed 's/\b500\b/600/g' file.xml` to replace only 500 not 5000.

Comment: A quick search returns this kind of thing: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6523886/2088135

Comment: Nice file samples. There isn't a single match in the xml file. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

`sed` is probably the wrong tool, and yet if it was certain no other of those *fileA.txt* numbers exist in *file.xml* but those to be changed, this should work:

```
paste file[AB].txt | sed 's/^.*/s#\\b&/;s/.*$/&#g/;s/\t/\\b#/' | sed -f - file.xml
```

First `paste` puts *fileA.txt* and *fileB.txt* together:

```
500 550
345 350
623 700
etc etc
```

Then `sed` converts that into future `sed` **s***ubstitute* commands:

```
s#\b500\b#550#g
s#\b345\b#350#g
s#\b623\b#700#g
s#\betc\b#etc#g
```

After which those are piped to `sed -f -`, which runs those commands.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that with `xmlstarlet`. For example,

```
xmlstarlet ed -u //price[text()='30.00'] -v '32.00' bookstore.xml
```

would replace a price of `30.00` with a price of `32.00` in your example file. You could build a command line from files as demonstrated by agc, but it would be onerous.