# Changing value in XML using Python

Tags: python, xml

```
<inboundContextData>
 <items>
    <item>
        <key>a</key>
        <value>One</value>
    </item>
    <item>
        <key>b</key>
        <value>Two</value>
    </item>
    <item>
        <key>c</key>
        <value>Three</value>
    </item>
 </items>
</inboundContextData>
```

I have to replace the values One, Two and Three with some other number using the python script. Please suggest what needs to done

Comment: Possible duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523886/find-and-replace-values-in-xml-using-python

Comment: The question is tagged "python", but there is no Python code. Please take some time to research the problem. Surely you have tried something yourself?

Answer (score 0):

For manipulating XML document you can use `BeautifulSoup` package. Example:

```
data = """
<inboundContextData>
<items>
    <item>
        <key>a</key>
        <value>One</value>
    </item>
    <item>
        <key>b</key>
        <value>Two</value>
    </item>
    <item>
        <key>c</key>
        <value>Three</value>
    </item>
</items>"""


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'xml')

my_new_value = 'XXX'

for value in soup.select('items > item > value'):
    value.clear()
    value.append(my_new_value)

print(soup.prettify())
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<inboundContextData>
 <items>
  <item>
   <key>
    a
   </key>
   <value>
    XXX
   </value>
  </item>
  <item>
   <key>
    b
   </key>
   <value>
    XXX
   </value>
  </item>
  <item>
   <key>
    c
   </key>
   <value>
    XXX
   </value>
  </item>
 </items>
</inboundContextData>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `ElementTree`

**Demo:**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree
et = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse(filename)
root = et.getroot()
for i in root.findall("item"):
    i.find("value").text = "NewNumber"

et.write(filename)
```

**Output:**

```
<items>
    <item>
        <key>a</key>
        <value>NewNumber</value>
    </item>
    <item>
        <key>b</key>
        <value>NewNumber</value>
    </item>
    <item>
        <key>c</key>
        <value>NewNumber</value>
    </item>
</items>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ElementTree`. With this you can load xml into a multidimensional list where you can access the elements hierarchically. For example, starting from root you xml can see as:

```
<inboundContextData> <- root
<items> root <- 0
    <item> root <- 0 <- 0
        <key>a</key>
        <value>One</value> root <-0 <-0<-1
    </item>
    <item>
        <key>b</key>
        <value>Two</value>
    </item>
    <item>
        <key>c</key>
        <value>Three</value>
    </item>
</items>
```

So, to alter the first "value" you would do so:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

xml = ET.parse('testfile.xml')
root = xml.getroot()

root[0][0][1].text = 'Five'

xml.write('testfile.xml')
```