# How to edit xml config file in python 3?

Tags: python, xml, config

I have a xml config file and needs to update particular attribute value.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <testCommnication>
          <connection intervalInSeconds="50" versionUpdates="15"/>
        </testCommnication>
</configuration>
```

I just need to update the "versionUpdates" value to "10".

How can i achieve this in python 3.

I have tried xml.etree and minidom and not able to achieve it.

Comment: Please share a relevant sample of the code you have tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find and Replace Values in XML using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523886/find-and-replace-values-in-xml-using-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `xml.etree.ElementTree` to modify the xml:
**Edit**: If you want to retail the attribute order, use `lxml` instead. To install, use `pip install lxml`

```
# import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from lxml import etree as ET
tree = ET.parse('sample.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

# modifying an attribute
for elem in root.iter('connection'):
    elem.set('versionUpdates', '10')

tree.write('modified.xml')   # you can write 'sample.xml' as well
```

Content now in `modified.xml`:

```
<configuration>
    <testCommnication>
          <connection intervalInSeconds="50" versionUpdates="10" />
        </testCommnication>
</configuration>
```

Comment: It's modifying the value but attribute places are sorting in alphabetical order.  Ex:  <connection  user="testing" intervalInSeconds="50" versionUpdates="10" />   showing as   <connection  intervalInSeconds="50" user="testing" versionUpdates="10" /> . It should not change the attribute places.  How can we do that?

Comment: Attribute places doesn't matter in xml

Comment: But our project requirement is like attribute should be in same order after modifying. How can we do that?

Comment: @rts: Edited the answer to use module `lxml`, just one line change. Please note this is not internal module, you have to install it

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xml.etree.ElementTree` in Python 3 to handle XML :

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree
config_file = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse('your_file.xml')
config_file.findall(".//connection")[0].set('versionUpdates', 10))
config_file.write('your_new_file.xml')
```