# Replace specific string in an XML file

Tags: python, xml, file

I want to replace a specific string in a file by a variable's value:

In my file there is these 2 lines:

```
<CtrlSum>10</CtrlSum>
```

```
<sum>45</sum>
```

I want to search for the value "10" and replace it by "45".

I tried something like that:

```
with open(path,'r+') as f:
    lst=f.readlines()
    for j in lst:
        if'sum' in j:
            Somme = j.split('>')[1].split('<')[0]
            print(Somme)

    for i in lst:
        if 'CtrlSum' in i:
            Ctrl = i.split('>')[1].split('<')[0]
    print (Ctrl)

    f.writelines(f.replace(Ctrl,Somme))
```

But I have this error:

> f.writelines(f.replace(Ctrl,Somme))
> AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'replace'

What is wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: `f` is a file. You can only call `.replace()` on a string (i.e. the result of `.read()`)

Comment: Usually I create another file, copy the modified content to it and then rename it to override the original

Comment: what are you trying to do? replace what string with what? - what are you planning to achieve with these splits?

Comment: i want to replace the value between < > on "CtrlSum" by value of "Sum" @DevCl9

Comment: Are you asking how to parse an XML or HTML file?

Comment: its an XML file i tried with elementTree but cant make it worked so im just working with it like its a simple file

Comment: Well, the answer to the actual question you have asked is "you can't use the `replace` method with a file object, you have to use it with a string", but that won't solve your problem.

Comment: This should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523886/find-and-replace-values-in-xml-using-python. If not, you should show a [mre] of input files, what exactly you have tried and what the problem was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do something like this:

```
import re

with open('a.txt','r') as f:
    text_value = f.read()

    sum_val = sum(map(int, re.findall(r'<sum>(\d+)</sum>', text_value)))

with open('a.txt','w') as f:
    f.write(re.sub(r'<CtrlSum>(.+)</CtrlSum>', f'<CtrlSum>{sum_val}</CtrlSum>', text_value))
```

No need for `readlines()` or `writelines()` or any loop. Just read the whole text with `.read()` -> process it -> `write()`.

Comment: Yeah but without readlines() i cant loop trough my files to seek different occurences of what i am searching for : in this case value between <> after "CtrlSum" String @DevCl9

Comment: WDYM? could you share a sample input file and the desired output? (if this code doesn't cut it)

Comment: imagine if in my file there is these 2 lines : 
<CtrlSum>10</CtrlSum>
 <sum>45</sum>
i want to search for the value "10" and replace it by "45" , sorry if its not very clear !
@DevCl9

Comment: Yeah ! but that append all the text after the first one , is there a way to overwrite it ?

Comment: Yeah but if there is multiple occurence of "Sum" is there any way to add them ?@DevCl9

Comment: You specifically said "`In my file there is these 2 lines:`" - anyway, what do you wish to happen if there are several such tags? replace with the nearest value?

Comment: Yes im sorry , no just add the sum of " sum " values and replace " ctrl " by this sum ! @DevCl9

Comment: @marcoAndrew updated! and please upvote/accept if you find it useful. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The replace() function can only be used on a string.
Your f isn't a string, it's the file itself. You need to call f.read() to get the file content as a string and call replace() on this.

EDIT: Check this link, it explains different methods to write on files :)

https://pythonexamples.org/python-replace-string-in-file/

Answer (score 0):

Use XML parsing

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<r><CtrlSum>10</CtrlSum>
<sum>45</sum></r>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
root.find('.//CtrlSum').text = root.find('.//sum').text
ET.dump(root)
```

output

```
<r>
   <CtrlSum>45</CtrlSum>
   <sum>45</sum>
</r>
```

Comment: But is this solution will work when the xml file will have a lot of element and child and subchild ? or is it just working with this example ?@balderman

Comment: Try it on your xml and give feedback

Answer (score 0):

XSLT 3.0 solution:

```
<xsl:transform version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
 <xsl:template match="CtrlSum/text()">
   <xsl:value-of select="//sum"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

(Using XSLT 1.0 is also possible, just a bit more verbose).