# to grep the parent pom version and replace with new value

Tags: python, xml, linux, shell, maven

i have an xml file in which i need to find the parent version and replace with a new value.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.test.proj</groupId>
        <artifactId>proj-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.0</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.test.child</groupId>
    <artifactId>sub-module</artifactId>
    <version>2.20.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>test</name>
    <description>test suite</description>
</project>
```

in the above xml, I am able to change the module version using mvn command, but unable to change the parent version using script. Is there any ways to grep and replace the value?

I tried to change using the python script

```py
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
print ElementTree(file="pom.xml").findtext("{http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0}parent/version")
```

By default is is taking the snapshot version only.

Comment: what value you want to replace with ?

Comment: @SoumendraMishra i want to provide the input value through jenkins parameter

For Example, if i trigger the jenkins build, it has to first grep and show the current parent version and has to replace with the new version that i am providing via Jenkins.

Comment: `"{http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0}version"` gets me the SNAPSHOT version. `"{http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0}parent/version"` gets me nothing at all. Are you trying to print out both of these, and then replace them both? With the same value?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is probably incomplete but at least here are the beginnings of an answer.

If you can use the stand-alone tool `xmlstarlet`, try this:

```sh
xmlstarlet sel -N m=http://maven.apache.or '//m:version' -n /tmp/pom.xml
```

Output:

```xml
1.1.0.0
2.20.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Then to modify,

```sh
xmlstarlet ed -N m=http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 -u '//m:version' -v 1.2.3.4  /tmp/pom.xml
```

Output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.test.proj</groupId>
    <artifactId>proj-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3.4</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.test.child</groupId>
  <artifactId>sub-module</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.3.4</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>test</name>
  <description>test suite</description>
</project>
```

Source / inspiration: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/398157/search-replace-in-xml-file-with-sed-or-awk and the [XML Starlet manual](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch04s01.html)

If you want to do this in Python then see e.g. [Find and Replace Values in XML using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523886/find-and-replace-values-in-xml-using-python)
(seriously think about migrating to Python 3 though!)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the parent version by using Maven itself:

`mvn versions:update-parent -DparentVersion=1.2.3`